# Ionic deploy we should remove plugin rm cordova-plugin-console

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Before ionic we deploy, we should take care to adjust plugins needed during development that should not be in production mode. For example, we probably don’t want the debug console plugin enabled, so we should remove it before generating the release builds:
$ ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console

**My question is do we need to add again cordova-plugin-console after release for testing our app or it will we added automatically in ionic serve ?**

Answer (score 0):

`ionic serve` calls `cordova prepare` internally. [cordova preapre](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/) does not add plugins. It only copies relevant files into the build folder.
When you remove the cordova plugin, it removes these files from your project directory. Without the files present `ionic serve` will not add the plugin.